# ps -ef crashes during Asterisk restart

Tags: linux, centos, gdb, glibc, ps

If I restart Asterisk, about 10 core dumps appear in /tmp directory, all with the same crash. Executing `ps -ef` manually does not reproduce crash.

gdb output:

```
Core was generated by `ps -ef'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  reset_global () at ps/global.c:362
362       look_up_our_self(&p);
(gdb)
```

Disassmble:

```
   0x0000000000403040 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000000403041 <+1>:     mov    $0xdeadbeef,%eax
   0x0000000000403046 <+6>:     push   %rbx
   0x0000000000403047 <+7>:     sub    $0x80028,%rsp
   0x000000000040304e <+14>:    mov    0x21147b(%rip),%rbx        # 0x6144d0 <selection_list>
   0x0000000000403055 <+21>:    cmp    %rax,%rbx
   0x0000000000403058 <+24>:    je     0x403084 <reset_global+68>
   0x000000000040305a <+26>:    test   %rbx,%rbx
   0x000000000040305d <+29>:    jne    0x40306b <reset_global+43>
   0x000000000040305f <+31>:    jmp    0x403084 <reset_global+68>
   0x0000000000403061 <+33>:    nopl   0x0(%rax)
   0x0000000000403068 <+40>:    mov    %rbp,%rbx
   0x000000000040306b <+43>:    mov    0x8(%rbx),%rdi
   0x000000000040306f <+47>:    mov    (%rbx),%rbp
   0x0000000000403072 <+50>:    callq  0x4017e8 <free@plt>
   0x0000000000403077 <+55>:    mov    %rbx,%rdi
   0x000000000040307a <+58>:    callq  0x4017e8 <free@plt>
   0x000000000040307f <+63>:    test   %rbp,%rbp
   0x0000000000403082 <+66>:    jne    0x403068 <reset_global+40>
   0x0000000000403084 <+68>:    lea    0x80010(%rsp),%rbx
   0x000000000040308c <+76>:    mov    $0x634680,%edi
   0x0000000000403091 <+81>:    movq   $0x0,0x211434(%rip)        # 0x6144d0 <selection_list>
=> 0x000000000040309c <+92>:    callq  0x401908 <look_up_our_self@plt>
   0x00000000004030a1 <+97>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x00000000004030a3 <+99>:    mov    %rbx,%rdx
   0x00000000004030a6 <+102>:   mov    $0x5413,%esi
   0x00000000004030ab <+107>:   mov    $0x1,%edi
   0x00000000004030b0 <+112>:   callq  0x401698 <ioctl@plt>
   0x00000000004030b5 <+117>:   cmp    $0xffffffffffffffff,%eax
       0x00000000004030b8 <+120>:   je     0x4032e0 <reset_global+672>
...
```

What is this: `0x0000000000403041 <+1>:     mov    $0xdeadbeef,%eax` ?

info registers:

```
(gdb) info registers
rax            0xdeadbeef       3735928559
rbx            0x7849d15d9e60   132258440519264
rcx            0x0      0
rdx            0x0      0
rsi            0x7849d15d9de0   132258440519136
rdi            0x634680 6506112
rbp            0x0      0x0
rsp            0x7849d1559e50   0x7849d1559e50
r8             0x0      0
r9             0xff3212ff2a1f09ff       -57962958069757441
r10            0x8      8
r11            0x206    518
r12            0x2      2
r13            0x7849d15da0a8   132258440519848
r14            0x0      0
r15            0x0      0
rip            0x40309c 0x40309c <reset_global+92>
eflags         0x10246  [ PF ZF IF RF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0
```

System info:

```
3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #7 SMP Wed Jan 27 18:05:09 CET 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

rpm -qa | grep glibc
glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64
glibc-debuginfo-common-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64
glibc-headers-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64
glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.i686
glibc-common-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64
glibc-debuginfo-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here, tried to reinstall Linux from scratch but getting same result.

Answer (score 2):

> `=> 0x000000000040309c <+92>:    callq  0x401908 <look_up_our_self@plt>`

It is somewhat unusual for a program to die on `CALL` (or `PUSH`) instruction, and whenever that happens, it's almost guaranteed that you have a stack overflow. Further,

> `0x0000000000403047 <+7>:     sub    $0x80028,%rsp`

this function requires half MiB of stack, which is also quite unusual, and large. Looking at the rest of disassembly, if `JE` at `0x403058` was taken, then `CALL` at `0x40309c` would be the first instruction trying to push something onto stack after the large decrement.

Conclusion: the environment in which Asterix executes `ps -ef` has a `uimit -s` that is set too small.

> What is this: `0x0000000000403041 <+1>:     mov    $0xdeadbeef,%eax` ?

The code compares `%RAX` with `selection_list`. The `0xdeadbeef` is clearly a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

Comment: Thank you for detailed comment. This issue was on OVH box with Centos 6.6 and custom 3.14.xx OVH kernel. I installed default Centos kernel, and problem disappeared, no more crashes afters asterisk restart.